# UI not updating from EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

For a project I use a very simple progress overlay.

It just displays a small marquee progressbar and covers the screen.

So in my ShellView I have

```
<Border Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="11"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="11"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Panel.ZIndex="3"
        Background="#9E000000"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="3"
        Visibility="{Binding IsProgressing,
                                 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">

        <!-- omitted progressbar, text etc -->
</Border>
```

And I have a very simple event, which just sets the Visibility (IsProgressing) binding and some text to show.

Whenever I want to have a progressbar, I just publish that event, like

```
_eventAggregator.Publish(new ProgressingChange(true, "Loading ..."));
```

This works very well so far, besides one case:

For the application I use events for navigation of my screens.

So there is another event which I publish, like:

```
_eventAggregator.Publish(new NavigationEvent(typeof(TargetViewModel)));
```

which just sets the target screen:

```
public void Handle(NavigationEvent navigate)
{
    var target = _screenFactory.FromType(navigate.TargetScreen);
    this.ActivateItem(target);
}
```

One of my Screens has lots of items and takes about 3 seconds to load.

So I wanted to show my Progress overlay while the screen is loading.

This is what does not work. Both the new Screen and the Overlay are
showing simultaneously when those events are combined.

This is:

```
_eventAggregator.Publish(new ProgressingChange(true, "Loading ..."));
_eventAggregator.Publish(new NavigationEvent(typeof(LongLoadingViewModel)));
```

For debugging reasons I did not deactivate the Progressing overlay to the 
what is happening.

So the screen is loaded, nothing is shown on the screen for about 3 seconds, and then
both the Progress overlay and the new screen are shown.

I have tried

- sleeping after publishing the ProgressingChange event
- sleeping in both event handlers
- running the publish of both events on separate threads
- running only one of those publishes on a separate threads
- tried to force UI update like this here [force UI update](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fce9b7b-4a13-4c8d-8c3e-562667851baa/forcing-update-of-ui-before-my-function-exits?forum=wpf)

What am I missing?

What is happening here?

How can I get that to work?

**-edit-**

Here is the code of my Handler method:

```
public void Handle(ProgressingChange progressing)
{
    this.IsProgressing= progressing.IsProgressing;
    this.ProgressingText= progressing.ProgressingText;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsProgressing);
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ProgressingText);  
    // of course, there is Notify in the setters themselves, too
}
```

And I used this code from the source linked above to force UI updates,
but that did not work

```
void AllowUIToUpdate() {

DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object parameter)
{
    frame.Continue = false;

    return null;
}), null);

Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);

}
```

Also, I tried publishing in a critical section to force the first 
publish to be executed before the second one, but that did not work either.

**-edit2-**
Code that at least shows the Progress overlay

```
_eventAggregator.Publish(new ProgressingChange(true, "Activating ..."));
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _eventAggregator.Publish(new NavigationEvent(typeof(LongLoadingViewModel)))), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Comment: Sleep() is of no use, but post the way you force the UI update. And  `Handle(ProgressingChange pc)`

Comment: If your screen takes a while to load, there might be nothing you can do - since there is only one "UI thread" it could be a measure/arrange or element generation bottleneck. During this time there might be a lot of blocking going on which is stopping the progress bar from showing until the components in your new screen have finished generating (no new render calls) - it's worth posting your `Handle<T>` methods so we can look at what's inside them just in case this isn't the case. I do find that using some 3rd party controls that are quite busy sometimes locks the UI for a brief pause...

Comment: Have added that code, please have a look

Comment: @Charleh Seems that it is a problem with the UI thread. The code in the answer works in a way, the overlay is shown, but the progressbar is not running. Perhaps this is the best I can do about it then?

Comment: Yes possibly - like I said, I've been using Telerik grid control - when you scroll performance is fine (because only new rows need to be updated as you scroll) but if you page, it does take a split second to arrange all the new rows. When the data is first displayed in the grid the pause is even more noticeable. This is probably because the grids virtualisation enables the existing row elements to be re-used for successive data-items but when a lot of rows need to be created at once there's a much bigger hit. I'd imagine the same thing is happening here and there's no much you can do

Comment: I do not have something special, just a Screen with two lists with some thousend nodes. I see that loading may be a problem, perhaps I can do something about that. But I still find it interesting that the overlay is not rendered until all the UI things are ready. Somehow I believed that should be more sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a hack, but you could try to first wait for the Border (porgress bar) to be rendered before the navigation-event is published. To do this, you might be able to adapt [the solution that is given here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ilich/archive/2012/10/16/running-code-when-windows-rendering-is-completed.aspx) to execute some code when the UI-thread is no longer busy (see link for full explanation):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Trace.WriteLine("DONE!", "Rendering")), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

If this works, then at least you have something to start off making the code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have placed the "hacky" line of code between the two `Publish` calls. But this does not work.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried? The purpose was to publish the navigation-event where 'TraceLine.Write' is called, such that the navigation-event is published only as soon as rendering is complete.

Comment: That works! The progress bar is blocked, but at least there is a clear message that something is going on!

Comment: Have added that code to the question. Just in case you want to see it.